# How to calculate the sum of values of dynamically created input?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

**Background**- I have created an app where the parent component can create and delete a input field *(child component)* on a click of a button. The input's value is recorded on screen through v-model

**Problem**- When a new input is created the previous value is replaced by the new input value.

**Expectation-** When a new input is created it adds the value of the previous input value

A visual for more clarity

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp8Mk.png

**Parent Component**

```
 <form-input v-for="n in count" :key="n" :value="expense" @input="expense = $event"></form-input>

      <button @click="addInputs">Add Expense</button>
      <button @click="deleteInputs">Delete</button>

      <p>Total Expense: {{ expense }}</p>

export default {
  components: {
    "form-input": formInput
  },
  name: "form",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      expense: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addInputs: function() {
      this.count++;
    },
    deleteInputs: function() {
      this.count--;
    }
  }
};
```

Child Component

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Expense" />
<input type="number" placeholder="Amount" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" />
```

Comment: You’re overwriting the expense in the parent with the last added child component. You should instead store individual expenses in an array. The total expense is then calculated by summing up the array. In this sense, you can use `v-model` inside the `v-for` loop since each child component will write to its respective element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I made a sandbox for you to see my solution for this as there are a lot of changes and you can see how it performs.

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-fire-kpwpp

The main points are:

1. You have to keep track of the values of each input separately. This is done using an array.
2. When this array is changed we recalculate the total expense

### Parent

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form-input v-for="(n, idx) in count" :key="n" :id="idx" @input="getExpense"></form-input>

    <button @click="addInputs">Add Expense</button>
    <button @click="deleteInputs">Delete</button>

    <p>Total Expense: {{ totalExpense }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  components: {
    "form-input": HelloWorld
  },
  name: "form",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      expenses: [],
      totalExpense: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addInputs: function() {
      this.count++;

      this.expenses[this.count - 1] = 0;
    },
    deleteInputs: function() {
      this.count--;
      this.expenses.pop();

      this.setTotalExpense();
    },
    getExpense(data) {
      this.expenses[data.id] = parseInt(data.value, 10) || 0;
      this.setTotalExpense();
    },
    setTotalExpense() {
      console.log(this.expenses);

      this.totalExpense = this.expenses.reduce((sum, val) => {
        return sum + val;
      }, 0);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

### Child

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Expense">
    <input
      type="number"
      placeholder="Amount"
      @input="$emit('input', { 
        value: $event.target.value,
        id
      })"
    >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    id: Number
  }
};
</script>
```

I used the `HelloWorld` template so that's why there are some references to that, but I'm sure you can easily clean that up :)

And also, there may be some small edge case bugs that you can clean up. This should point you in the right direction though.

Comment: Hey T.Short appreciate all the help so far.  The one thing that I am confused about is the id prop that binded by the index in the parent component

Comment: It's used to keep track of the child components. So when you get an event from a child component, the parent can know which child it came from.

Comment: I am having trouble trying to save value of the Expense input from the child component into an array in the parent similar to the way you did with the Amount input

Comment: @EddieWeldon Could you create a new question for this? And tag me in the comments and I will look into it. It would make it easier and clearer, thanks.